# How to "move" value in Excel

Tags: excel

Please help me how to do this. Please see the image below:
[image: Desired result]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider using a ***Pivot Table***

Comment: hi Gary's Student, Thank you for your help. But I just move the value - not sum of price,as the table in image. Do you have any suggestion else?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is best accomplished with a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-create-a-pivottable-74ce8afc-2446-4816-80ee-20ca7fb71793). In this case you would select "name" for the Rows, "Size" for the columns, and Sum of "Price" for the values.

Comment: hi David, I don't want to make sum of "price" just move the value as the image describe.

Comment: @LêMinhTrung Since you don't have any repeated combinations of name and size, the sum is effectively just moving the values. If you do have repeated combinations, you'd need to decide how you want to handle them. Give it a try and see if the result is what you're looking for. If it gives an undesired result, edit the question with what you got, and why it isn't desired.